# Units in gravitational $N$ body simulations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, simulations, units, dimensional-analysis

I am trying to write a code in Python to simulate $N$ bodies interacting through gravity. In particular I am trying to see whether a system of particles with random initial positions and zero velocity will fall into a viral equilibrium.

I understand that in $N$ body simulations, it is advisable to set $G=1$ and $M=1$. However, having done this what then are my units of time or length or energy?

Comment: Have you just looked at equations where $G$ and $M$ appear and applied dimensional analysis to them? It's not hard.

Comment: I have tried though have ended up confusing my self. The units of G are 'kg^{-1} m^3 s^2' but I'm confused how this works in conjunction with the mass

Comment: If you intend to model point particles, there is no typical scale of length or time in your question about virial equilibrium, so units do not matter for the physics part of the model. In computer the numbers will be stored in finite memory and thus processed inaccurately and units used have some impact there, but this is very probably negligible to errors due to finite time of computation you will probably want to devote to it.

Comment: I think compiled language would be better choice for such numerically demanding task, especially if you want to have lots  (hundreds, thousands) particles. It is probably harder to write it in compiled language such as Fortran or C, but when you're done, your simulation will run much faster. Maybe you would be interested in Nim - it is a recent effort for a compiled language with syntax similar to Python. I did not try it, but there is a compiler and the examples on its site http://nim-lang.org/ look nice.

Comment: I am modelling point particles, though with a softening term for close interactions. I am trying to track their energies, but what would the units of energy be (and would they be the same for grav potential/kinetic)?

Comment: I am trying to follow what is outlined here: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WYQmYyy3f98C&pg=PA112&lpg=PA112&dq=crossing+time+n+body+units&source=bl&ots=nS43fkQqII&sig=dN05JHD1vmTMtIKy_BFchoYatK8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=f9zQVP63CsGt7AadoIGgAg&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=crossing%20time%20n%20body%20units&f=false but am having a hard time of it

Comment: [this](https://github.com/jamiefarnes/negative-mass-simulator) may be of help, as a reference for a similar program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, scientific computer code is written in such a way that variables have no "knowledge" of the units they are intended to represent. (Of course, you could be arbitrarily sophisticated in the way you write your program, e.g. by defining classes that keep track of dimensionality and used units, and then use these classes to define your variables. But that is the exception, in my experience.)

Assume, for generality, that you have bodies of different masses. You may choose one of them, called, say, $M_0 \ne 0$, to be the scale you use to measure masses. So, the mass of object $1$ may now be measured in multiples of $M_0$, e.g. you could have $M_1 = 42 M_0$, and likewise $M_2 = 0.01 M_0$. It is then common to set $M_0=1$, both on paper as well as in the program, and consequently drop the term $M_0$ altogether. Similarly, you can set $G=1$. This is often done, but in what follows, keep the initial situation with $M_0$ still present in mind.

So, $R$ being the distance between $M_1$ and $M_2$, you may write for the potential energy $V$, either on paper or in your code,
$$
V = - \frac{42 \cdot 0.01}{R}
$$
Now, $R$ may as well be measured as multiples of some characteristic length $R_0$ which you set to unity, so that all that remains for $V$ is a real number.

Your question, if I understood it correctly, is now how one can make sense of a calculated result of, say, $V = - 0.42$ (as in the case where, by coincidence or design, $R=1$.)

To do this, it may be helpful to review what has been done to reach this point: By convention, we agreed to measure masses as multiples of $M_0$, gravitational coupling strengths as multiples of $G$, and distances as multiples of $R_0$. However, let's not set $M_0=G=R_0=1$ this time, and consequently let's not drop those constants from our expressions.

So, instead of
$$
V = - G \frac{M_1 M_2}{R}
$$
one can write without loss of generality (see e.g. the definitions of $M_1$ and $M_2$ above)
$$
\left(v \cdot V_0\right) = - \left(g \cdot G\right) \frac{ \left(m_1 \cdot M_0\right) \left(m_2 \cdot M_0\right)}{\left(r \cdot R_0\right)}
$$
where all of $g=1$, $m_1 = 42$, $m_2 = 0.01$, $v$, and $r$ are dimensionless real numbers, and are the quantities you probably encounter in your program. The potential energy is now measured as a multiple of some characteristic energy $V_0$, i.e. $V=v \cdot V_0$.

So, what your computer program may calculate is actually the dimensionless quantity $v=-0.42$, which measures the multiples of $V_0$, so that the potential energy, with the correct dimensions, is $V=-0.42 V_0$. What remains is to understand what $v=-1$, i.e. $V=-V_0$, means in terms of, say, SI units. You would achieve $v=-1$ for example for $m_1=m_2=g=r=1$, so that
$$
-V_0 = - G \frac{M_0^2}{R_0}
$$
Depending on the values chosen for $M_0$ and $R_0$ (and $G$, if that is regarded a "choice"), $V_0$ is now fixed and known as well.

If you wanted to produce a graph of the dependence of the potential energy on the spatial separation of two fixed masses, you would the probably label the x-axis either $r$ or $R/R_0$, and the y-axis either $v$ or $V / \left(G \frac{M_0^2}{R_0}\right)$.

I hope this helps. Please feel free to ask for clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

[Kepler's Third Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion) is
$$\frac{T^2}{r^3} = \frac{4 \pi^2}{GM}$$
or equivalently
$$
\frac G{4\pi^2} = \frac{r^3}{T^2M}
$$
If you're modeling our solar system you can set 
\begin{align}
G &= 4\pi^2\frac{\text{AU}^3}{\text{year}^2 M_\odot}
\end{align}
where "AU" is the astronomical unit and $M_\odot$ is the mass of the sun. Then if you put an object with mass 1 (the sun) at the origin and a negligibly-massive object in a circular orbit at radius 1 (a.u., where earth orbits) you should find a period of 1 (year).

Here's a code snippet from a similar program of mine:

```
G = 4 * np.pi**2        ## in solar masses, AU, years
msun, au, year = np.ones(3)
km  = 1.0 / 1.5e8       ## one kilometer
m   = km  / 1e3
kg  = 1.0 / 2e30        ## one kilogram
sec = 1e-7 / pi         ## one second
joule = kg * (m / sec)**2
```

Now if I have a quantity whose *dimension* is energy, I can divide by `joule` to get a value in those units, even though in my strange "natural" units energies will have values near unity.